# I cannot access custom VLC GUI in Windows XP (virtual machine)

Tags: windows, windows-xp, vlc, libvlc

I have a problem with custom build of VLC 3.0.11.1 Vetinari. I cannot access VLC gui, only I can do terminal, but I don't know how to get access GUI.

```
VLC media player - 3.0.11.1 Vetinari
Copryight c 1996-2020 the VideoLAN team.

Warning: if you cannot access the GUI anymore, open a command-line window,
go to the directory where you installed VLC and run "vlc -I qt"
vlc -I qt
Unknown command `vlc`. Type `help` for help.
```

Is there any possible how can I get access GUI of custom build VLC?
[image: VLC Media Player terminal in Windows XP]

Comment: Do you have QT? Did you follow https://wiki.videolan.org/Win32Compile/ ?

Comment: please install the latest stable version of VLC, and SP2 pack